# Is it possible to "donate" a data pack to a Git LFS repository so I can pull a file from it?

Tags: github, git-lfs

I tried to download a large file from a Github LFS repository, using the command "git lfs pull." However, I got the following response: "batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Purchase more data packs to restore access." The only issue is, I don't own this repository, so purchasing data packs for my own account won't help at all. So, is there any way I can purchase a data pack and then "donate" it to the repository I'm trying to download the large file from? If not, is there any other way I can download a file from a Github LFS repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/nassl/issues/17) from 2017 illustrates that:

- even forking the repository would not solve the issue
- contacting the owner of the repo and giving (donating) a [GitHub Gift Card](https://github.myshopify.com/products/gift-card) would be a workaround.

I mentioned that same issue in "[How to get large files from git-lfs when error even though you have credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56412331/6309)", with an alternative approach.